# Construct two functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying $f \ne O(g), g \ne O(f)$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Construct two functions $  f,g:   R^+ → R^+ $ satisfying:

1. $f, g$ are continuous;
2. $f, g$ are monotonically increasing;
3. $f \ne O(g)$ and $g \ne O(f)$.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that such functions might not exist?

Comment: If both $f,g$ are logarithmico-exponential, then either $f=O(g)$ or $g=O(f)$. Most functions encountered in practice are of this form.

Comment: Does the term logarithmico-exponential have a formal definition?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are many examples for such functions. Perhaps the easiest way to understand how to get such an example, is by manually constructing it.

Let's start with function over the natural numbers, as they can be continuously completed to the reals.

A good way to ensure that $f\neq O(g)$ and $g\neq O(f)$ is to *alternate* between their orders of magnitude. For example, we could define

$f(n)=\begin{cases}
n & n \text{ is odd}\\
n^2 & n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}$

Then, we could have $g$ behave the opposite on the odds and evens. However, this **doesn't work** for you, because these functions are not monotonically increasing.

However, the choice of $n,n^2$ was somewhat arbitrary, and we could simply increase the magnitudes so as to have monotonicity. This way, we may come up with:

$f(n)=\begin{cases}
n^{2n} & n \text{ is odd}\\
n^{2n-1} & n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}$, and 
$g(n)=\begin{cases}
n^{2n-1} & n \text{ is odd}\\
n^{2n} & n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}$

Clearly these are monotone functions. Also, $f(n)\neq O(g(n))$, since on the odd integers, $f$ behaves like $n^{2n}$ while $g$ behaves like $n^{2n-1}=n^{2n}/n=o(n^{2n})$, and vice-versa  on the evens.

Now all you need is to complete them to the reals (e.g. by adding linear parts between the integers, but this is really beside the point).

Also, now that you have this idea, you could use the trigonometric functions in order to construct ``closed formulas'' for such functions, since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are oscillating, and peak on alternating points.

Comment: Can we say that $f(n) \in O(n^{2n})$ and $g(n) \in O(n^{2n})$? $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are as defined in your answer.

Comment: Yes. We can even say that $f(n)\le n^{2n}$ (similarly for $g$), which is stronger than $O$.

Answer (score -3):

Good illustration for me is:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2B2x%2C+cos%28x%29%2B2x

$$
f(n) =2x+sin(x)
$$
$$
g(n) =2x+cos(x)
$$
$$
f\neq O(g)
$$
$$
g\neq O(f)
$$

Comment: Actually they are both $O$ of each other.